# Minikube - Permission denied to access Postgres data /var/lib/postgresql/data

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, minikube

The logs of the postgres pod show permission error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: error: could not access directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Permission denied
```

Here is my pg.yaml manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/data
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:14
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: admin
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: admin
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb 
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

I mounted local path where I want to persist postgres data like this:

```
minikube mount /home/myuser/myproject/data:/mnt/data
```

I tried to add subPath as another post suggested but it did not help. What am I missing? Thank you!

**EDIT**

Per @DavidMaze I tested this yaml file. I do not get a permission error but postgres data does not persist. Here is the file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres

---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:14
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: admin
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: admin
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb 
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

Comment: have you tried with securityContext: runAsUser: 0. so it executes internally as root ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I set `spec.template.spec.SecurityContext.runAsUser` to 0 in deployment manifest, but still the same permission error.

Comment: Minikube [includes a persistent volume provisioner](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#dynamic-provisioning-and-csi); if you let the cluster create the PersistentVolume, does it work better?  (So delete the PersistentVolume and the PVC `storageClassName:`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze if I delete PV and PVC,  the pod is in Running state and I can exec into the container with `psql` but data does not persist. Here are my steps:
1. `minikube mount /home/n/projects/minikube-pg-test/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`
2. `k apply -f pg.yaml`
All is fine, I can create a new database when I exec into the container, but if I delete it and recreate, the new db is gone, and the `data` folder on the host is empty

Comment: Keep the PersistentVolumeClaim, but delete the `storageClassName:` setting. Don't manually create the PersistentVolume.

Comment: @DavidMaze I made the change you suggested and posted the edited file above, but postgres data still does not persist

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've mounted a different folder with `Minikube` according to the `mountPath` specified.

So if you mount in Minikube like in the question, edit the mountPath accordingly:

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /mnt/data
    name: postgredb
```

Then, check if the folder `/mnt/data` exist and create it of not:

```
mkdir /mnt/data
```

Set the right permission and add your username as owner:

```
sudo chmod 775 /mnt/data
sudo chown $(whoami) /mnt/data
```

Finally initialize the database `initdb /mnt/data`

Comment: where is this folder need to be created? On the host or in Minikube VM? On Mac OS with Kubernetes that comes with Docker Desktop I did not have to do anything manual like that - the manifests would take care of those details, so I am not sure if this is Minikube issue

Comment: The issue is that your folder in the mountPath is different from what you mount in minikube. I updated my answer with the right path of the folder.

Comment: Here are my steps:
1. `minikube mount /home/n/projects/minikube-pg-test/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`
2. changed yaml file so that both `hostPath.path` and `volumeMounts.mountPath` are both set to `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. I still get initdb: error: could not access directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Permission denied